# addParticipant to one-on-one conversations(escalation) and startOnlineMeeting return service failure

Tags: c#, skype-for-business, ucwa

I have been having some trouble with the UCWA API when attempting to create outgoing invitations to multi-party conversations.
I have created user endpoints and am able to carry out one-on-one chats. I have also managed to join multi-party conversations on receiving incoming invitations. However,

1) When I try creating ad hoc online meetings through startOnlineMeeting or try using joinOnlineMeeting to create new meeting

2) When I use addParticipant to existing one-on-one conversation, to escalate conversation to multiparty meeting and send out a participant invite

I find that though the requests succeed with a 201, the first event I get on the channel is a onlineMeetingInvitation/participantInvitation failure with reason,

"reason": {
            "code": "ServiceFailure",
            "message": "Your request couldn't be completed."
          }

Any idea where i am going wrong? These operations seem to go smoothly when attempted through desktop client. 
All help will be appreciated!

Comment: What does the request body look like when you call addParticipant?

Comment: { "operationId" : <operationId>, to": <sipuri> }. Returns a 201. I find this works just fine when used with a conversation that is already a multiparty conference.

Comment: Are you seeing this issue with all users when trying to escalate a P2P conversation to a multi-party conference?  Is the user able to call addParticipants in a multi-party conference and have that participant added?

Comment: Yes, all user throw the same issues and yes, i can call this successfully for multi-party conferences. Since startOnlineMeeting also gives me very similar problems, I feel that the problem may lie in my ability to start a conference.